# Problem with equation not centering

Tags: equations, matrices

I have a problem with the second equation not centering when split. Here is my code:

```
\begin{equation} 
    \begin{split}
        \textnormal{A}= 
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \cos(\pi/4) & -\sin(\pi/4) & 0\\
            \sin(\pi/4) & \cos(\pi/4) & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}
        ;
        \textnormal{B}=
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \cos(-\pi/4) & -\sin(-\pi/4) & 0\\
            \sin(-\pi/4) & \cos(-\pi/4) & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}\\
        \\
        \textnormal {AB}=\textnormal {BA}
        =
        \begin{pmatrix}
            1 & 0 & 0\\
            0 & 1 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{split}
    \label{eq:inverse2}
\end{equation}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: unrelated to the alignment, but you should (probably) use `\mathrm{A}` not `\textnormal{A}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `gathered` environment provided by `amsmath`

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:inverse2}
    \begin{gathered}
        \matr{A}= 
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \cos(\pi/4) & -\sin(\pi/4) & 0\\
            \sin(\pi/4) & \hphantom{-}\cos(\pi/4) & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}\\[2ex]
        \matr{B}=
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \cos(-\pi/4) & -\sin(-\pi/4) & 0\\
            \sin(-\pi/4) & \hphantom{-}\cos(-\pi/4) & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}\\[2ex]
      \matr {A}\matr{B}=\matr {B}\matr{A}
        =
        \begin{pmatrix}
            1 & 0 & 0\\
            0 & 1 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{gathered}
    \end{equation}


\end{document}
```

In my opinion `split` is best suited when one has to write a single long equation spanning more lines. Yours is clearly not the case.

Please consider also the `gather` environment (without equation) if you want to have one equation number per line.

The `amsmath` package documentation defines these and other useful environments, I invite you to browse through it to choose which one is best for your application.

**Also, important:**

1. To display roman in math environment, use `\mathrm` command;
2. Also, if you find yourself dealing with matrices, it would be better to define a command that represents their name in roman font, ie a shortcut to `\mathrm` to typeset them (quickly interchangeable if you want to and more readable). I defined the `\matr` command in this spirit (thanks to @egreg)

*EDIT*

Also, thanks to @egreg, I have noticed that the equation is best suited over three lines, since the two matrices are quite big; I reorganized the whole thing in a (I think) better fashion

[image]

Comment: @Mico thanks, I corrected it, I pasted the wrong code (and the right one took me a bit of time to edit)

Comment: this is nitpicking, but i think it would look nicer if the minus sign in the second column of the matrices didn't cause "sin" and "cos" to be offset from one another.  `\hphantom{-}` would shift the "cos" to the right just enough to line them up.

Comment: @barbarabeeton you are right, thanks; I just corrected it

Answer (score 2):

You should use `gathered`, not `split`, which is done to align parts of equations. I also suggest you use the `\mfrac` command from `nccmath` (medium-sized fraction, ~ 80 % of `\displaystyle`) in the place of `a/b` which uses more horizontal spacing, and add some spacing between the two matrices in the first line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
        \mathrm{A}=
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \cos(\pi/4) & -\sin(\pi/4) & 0\\
            \sin(\pi/4) & \cos(\pi/4) & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}
        ;\quad
        \mathrm{B}=
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \cos(-\pi/4) & -\sin(-\pi/4) & 0\\
            \sin(-\pi/4) & \cos(-\pi/4) & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}
        \\[1ex]
        \mathrm{AB}=\mathrm{BA}
        =
        \begin{pmatrix}
            1 & 0 & 0\\
            0 & 1 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{gathered}
    \label{eq:inverse2}
\end{equation}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \mathrm{A}=
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \cos\bigl(\mfrac{\pi}{4}\bigr) & -\sin\bigl(\mfrac{\pi}{4}\bigr) & 0\\
            \sin\bigl(\mfrac{\pi}{4}\bigr) & \cos\bigl(\mfrac{\pi}{4}\bigr) & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}
        ;\quad
        \mathrm{B}=
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \cos\bigl(-\mfrac{\pi}{4}\bigr) & -\sin\bigl(-\mfrac{\pi}{4}\bigr) & 0\\
            \sin\bigl(-\mfrac{\pi}{4}\bigr) & \cos\bigl(-\mfrac{\pi}{4}\bigr) & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
        \\[1ex]
        \mathrm{AB}=\mathrm{BA}
        =
        \begin{pmatrix}
            1 & 0 & 0\\
            0 & 1 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{gathered}
    \label{eq:inverse2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]